# How to use Derby SQLState constants

Tags: java, derby

My Java app is communicating with Apache Derby 10.8.1.2 DB.
I catch SQL exception and want to test for a specific case: `LANG_DUPLICATE_KEY_CONSTRAINT`
I was not able to find proper .jar to import `org.apache.derby.shared.common.reference` that supposedly contains this constant.

Even Derby Developer's Guide suggests test like:

```
if ( SQLState.equals( "23505" ) )
```

Question is, why test for a static string instead of a constant? I would expect something like:

```
if ( SQLState.equals( SQLState.LANG_DUPLICATE_KEY_CONSTRAINT ) )
```

Comment: You could certainly write your own class which provided such symbolic references; it would help clarify your own code and make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not like the answer ... but here it is:

SqlState was deliberately not included in any of the jar files, to try to minimize the size of Derby.  Quoting from the package description:

> **Package org.apache.derby.shared.common.reference Description**
>
> Useful constants that the Java compiler will in-line. A collection of reference interfaces that contain primitive or String constants. Such constants will be in-lined by the Java compiler hopefully leading to smaller footprint, than a reference to a field entails. Fields in interfaces are automatically public, static and final, hence constants.
>
> These classes should not need to be shipped with any of the Derby jar files. If one is shipped with a Jar file then it most likely means the field representing the constant was a non-String Object (e.g. new Integer(1)) or the final field is a calculated value that could not be resolved to a constant by the Java compiler.